# convert JSON array to bash array preserving whitespaces

Tags: arrays, json, bash, jq

I want to transform JSON file into bash array of strings that i will later be able to iterate over. My JSON structure is as follows:

```
[
  {
    "USERID": "TMCCP",
    "CREATED_DATE": "31/01/2020 17:52"
  },
  {
    "USERID": "TMCCP",
    "CREATED_DATE": "31/01/2020 17:52"
  }
]
```

And this is my bash script:

```
test_cases=($(jq -c '.[]' data.json))
echo ${test_cases[0]}
echo ${test_cases[1]}
echo ${test_cases[2]}
echo ${test_cases[3]}
```

As you can see it returns array with 4 elements instead of 2. Output:

```
{"USERID":"TMCCP","CREATED_DATE":"31/01/2020
17:52"}
{"USERID":"TMCCP","CREATED_DATE":"31/01/2020
17:52"}
```

For some reason having whitespace in date field causes some parsing issues. Any idea how to get over this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`readarray`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html#index-readarray) instead.

```
$ readarray -t test_cases < <(jq -c '.[]' file)
$ declare -p test_cases
declare -a test_cases=([0]="{\"USERID\":\"TMCCP\",\"CREATED_DATE\":\"31/01/2020 17:52\"}" [1]="{\"USERID\":\"TMCCP\",\"CREATED_DATE\":\"31/01/2020 17:52\"}")
```

And `read` can be used as shown below where `readarray` is unavailable.

```
IFS=$'\n' read -d '' -a test_cases < <(jq -c '.[]' file)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `readarray` to populate the array, rather than using an unquoted command substitution; `bash` doesn't care about JSON quoting when it splits the result into separate words.

```
readarray -t test_cases < <(jq -c '.[]' data.json)
```

In `bash` 3.2 (which is what you appear to be stuck with), you need something slightly more unwieldy

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
    test_cases+=("$line")
done < <(jq -c '.[]' data.json)
```